# Call function with completion handler

Tags: swift

I created the function below but I'm not sure how to call it, it complains saying:

```
Type 'T.Type' cannot conform to 'Decodable'
```

Here's how I'd like to call it:

```
let result = getApiData(modelToDecode: MyModel, url: "abc")
```

This is what I've tried:

```
func getApiData<T : Decodable>(modelToDecode: T.Type, url: String) -> Any? {
    // I get an error below
    fetchDataAndDecode(url: String, modelToDecode: T.Type) { result in
    }

    // temp placeholder
    return nil
}

func fetchDataAndDecode<T : Decodable>(url: String, modelToDecode: T.Type, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<T.Type, NetworkError>) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
        completionHandler(.failure(NetworkError.badURL))
        return
    }

    AF.request(url, method: .get).validate().responseData { response in
        guard let data = response.data else {
            completionHandler(.failure(NetworkError.apiFailed))
            return
        }

        do {
            // Decode the data
            let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(modelToDecode.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completionHandler(.success(decodedData as! T.Type))
            }
        } catch(let error) {
            print(" Error on afRequest(): \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

How can I call it inside the class properly?

Comment: You should call `fetchDataAndDecode(url: url, modelToDecode: modelToDecode)` instead.

Comment: If I remove the `Void` and place `Any?` I would get a warning on the `completionHandler` saying: Result of call to function returning `'Any?'` is unused. Am I missing something? @RickyMo

Comment: If you declare a function to return `Any?` instead of `Void`, you must return something in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result should be `Result<T, NetworkError>`. No need to add `modelToDecode` to your method declaration. You can explicitly set the resulting type in your async call. Btw you should the completion handler as well if you fail to decode your data:

```
enum NetworkError: Error {
    case badURL, apiFailed, corruptedData
}
```

---

Your method should look like this:

```
func fetchDataAndDecode<T: Decodable>(url: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<T, NetworkError>) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
        completionHandler(.failure(.badURL))
        return
    }

    AF.request(url, method: .get).validate().responseData { response in
        guard let data = response.data else {
            completionHandler(.failure(.apiFailed))
            return
        }

        do {
            let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completionHandler(.success(decodedData))
            }
        } catch {
            completionHandler(.failure(.corruptedData))
        }
    }
}
```

---

And when calling it you need to explicitly set the resulting type:

```
fetchDataAndDecode(url: "yourURL") { (result: Result<WhatEver, NetworkError>) in 
    // switch the result here
}
```

Comment: Very nice optimization of the code! Love it, as well as the working answer. Many thanks